# How to create DbSet function from adding a table in Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am maintaining the system from previous employees and I can't seem to replicate the creation this model `public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }` inside context.cs

I have my entity, **Bank.edmx** then I will add a table. *Account*.

They have this line of code generated from the context.cs but it doesn't appear on my solution when I add the table.[image]

I tried CodeFirst, but its not what they used, it's EF designer from database.
Anything I am missing when adding the tables for the DbSet to appear?

Answer (score 0):

after trying and trying, I found it. 
You have to tick `Pluralize or singularize generated object names` for it to have a DbSet

[image]